# Multiple queries & LastInsertId

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How wrong is that query? Can I insert multiple queries like that?
Can I use `lastInsertId` like that?

```
$pdo = Database::connect();
    $dflt = 'DEFAULT';

    $query1 = "INSERT INTO utilizador(email, pass, nome, dt_registo, tipo, activo) 
                  VALUES (:email, '$hashed_password', :nome, :dt_registo, :tipo, :activo)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query1);
    $stmt->execute();
    $insertedid = $pdo->lastInsertId("utilizador");

    $query2 ="INSERT INTO aluno(morada, cd_postal, cidade, utilizador_id)
                VALUES (:morada, :cpostal, :cidade,'$insertedid')";

    $stmt2 = $pdo->prepare($query2);
    $stmt2->execute();

    $hashed_password = hash( 'sha512', $_POST['password']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email',$_POST['email']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':nome',$_POST['nome']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':dt_registo',$dflt);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tipo',$dflt);
    $stmt->bindParam(':activo',$dflt);
    $stmt->bindParam(':morada',$_POST['morada']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':cpostal',$_POST['cpostal']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':cidade',$_POST['cidade']);

    if($stmt->execute()){        
        echo "Product was created.";
    }else{
        echo "Unable to create product.";
    }
    Database::disconnect();
}
catch(PDOException $exception){
    echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
}
```

I've already been searching but couldn't find how to use both in a query and I already expired all the solutions, not sure which is wrong.

**EDIT:**
I'm starting to think its more than the query, if someone notice something..

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).on('submit', '#create-aluno-form', function() {
    // show a loader img
    $('#loader-image').show();

    // post the data from the form
    $.post("registar.php", $(this).serialize())
        .done(function(data) {           
            // show create product button
            $('#create-aluno').show();
            showProducts();
        });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I modified my answer can you check it once. You satisfied my answer can you give a blue tick mark please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your statement fails to insert, Your code is full of problems:

- You used prepare statement but yet you put values in the query string
- hashed_password is undefined in the first query
- You try to bind multiple queries at once
- wrong order prepare the first query, execute , then bind the parameters
  -`$pdo->lastInsertId();` is enough not sure why you pass `"utilizador"`

---

Try this approach:

```
try{
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $dflt = 'DEFAULT';
    $hashed_password = hash( 'sha512', $_POST['password']);

    $query1 = "INSERT INTO utilizador(email, pass, nome, dt_registo, tipo, activo) 
                  VALUES (:email, :pass, :nome, :dt_registo, :tipo, :activo)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query1);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email',$_POST['email']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pass',$hashed_password);
    $stmt->bindParam(':nome',$_POST['nome']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':dt_registo',$dflt);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tipo',$dflt);
    $stmt->bindParam(':activo',$dflt);
    if($stmt->execute()){
        //query1 success
        $insertedid = $pdo->lastInsertId();
        $query2 ="INSERT INTO aluno(morada, cd_postal, cidade, utilizador_id)
                  VALUES (:morada, :cpostal, :cidade, :utilizador_id)";
        $stmt2 = $pdo->prepare($query2);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':morada',$_POST['morada']);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':cpostal',$_POST['cpostal']);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':cidade',$_POST['cidade']);
        $stmt2->bindParam(':utilizador_id',$insertedid);
        if($stmt2->execute()){        
            //query2 success
        }else{
            //query2 failed
        }
    }else{
            //query1 failed
    }

    Database::disconnect();
}
catch(PDOException $exception){
    echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think these will useful to you.

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO utilizador(email, pass, nome, dt_registo, tipo, activo) 
              VALUES (:email, '$hashed_password', nome, :dt_registo, :tipo, :activo)";

 $query_1 = " INSERT INTO aluno(morada, cd_postal, cidade, utilizador_id) 
                      VALUES (:morada, :cpostal, :cidade, mysql_insert_id())";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt_1 = $pdo->prepare($query_1);
```

these will useful to you.

```
 mysql_select_db('test');
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (name) values ('venkatesh')");
 printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
```

Thank you.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php =>  i think these link is useful to you check it please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO utilizador(email, pass, nome, dt_registo, tipo, activo) 
              VALUES (:email, '$hashed_password', nome, :dt_registo, :tipo, :activo);";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query1);
    $stmt->execute();

     $query2 ="INSERT INTO aluno(morada, cd_postal, cidade, utilizador_id) 
                        VALUES (:morada, :cpostal, :cidade, LAST_INSERT_ID());";
    $stmt2 = $pdo->prepare($query2);
    $stmt2->execute();
```

Because insert the query not get last insert id. so separate those queries

Comment: No sir, still the same.

Comment: use this line before $query2 start.     **$Insertid = $pdo->lastInsertId("utilizador");**  and replace  LAST_INSERT_ID() to **$Insertid**

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the

```
mysql_insert_id()
```

to get the last inserted record's id

Answer (score 0):

see here

```
INSERT INTO questions VALUES(NULL, 'My question');

INSERT INTO answers VALUES(NULL, LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'Answer 1');
INSERT INTO answers VALUES(NULL, LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'Answer 2');
INSERT INTO answers VALUES(NULL, LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'Answer 3');
```

Now I Have using LAST_INSERT_ID();

```
INSERT INTO answers VALUES
          (NULL, LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'Answer 1') , 
          (NULL, LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'Answer 2') , 
          (NULL, LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'Answer 3');
```

OR

also we can try this way

```
INSERT INTO questions VALUES(NULL, 'My question');
SET @id = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());
INSERT INTO answers VALUES(NULL, @id, 'Answer 1');
INSERT INTO answers VALUES(NULL, @id, 'Answer 2');
INSERT INTO answers VALUES(NULL, @id, 'Answer 3');
```

It was just an example for you

Answer (score 0):

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO utilizador(email, pass, nome, dt_registo, tipo, activo) 
              VALUES (:email, '$hashed_password', nome, :dt_registo, :tipo, :activo);";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query1);
    $stmt->execute();
    $insertedid = $pdo->lastInsertId("utilizador");

     $query2 ="INSERT INTO aluno(morada, cd_postal, cidade, utilizador_id)
```

Ref link:-http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/169597-pdolastinsertid/

```
                        VALUES (:morada, :cpostal, :cidade,'$insertedid'
);";
    $stmt2 = $pdo->prepare($query2);
    $stmt2->execute();
```

Comment: I do think this is the proper way, however i just updated the post since i tried to insert the first query only and didn't work anyway, check it again please.